# Anchor text input to line on image

Tags: html, css

I want to anchor a text input box to an exact spot on an image.  I can do this with CSS no problem, but as soon as i resize my window, the input box loses its alignment.

I want to be able to allow resizing of my window to a certain extent, but must keep the text boxes anchored to a very specific spot.

See the attached HTML/CSS.  I want the "Firstname" input to ALWAYS sit on the name line of the image.

HTML.....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link href="style1.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
          <div id="block">
            <div>
                <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_RNrl2Gr0VwI/TJXG8dG6oeI/AAAAAAAADFY/pq6J6WQIW60/s1600/Arkham+Sanitarium+Admission+Form+Sample.jpg">
            </div>
            <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="fn" class="one">one</a>

        </div>
    </div><!--/content-->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS.....

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#block{ float:left; width:100%; max-width: 1000px; min-width: 600px; position: relative; }

#content{
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#block img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

input.one{  position: absolute; top:15%; left:12%; display:block; background:rgba(0,255,0,0.5);}
```

Help!

Comment: cant locate any issue  http://jsfiddle.net/ucUmD/

Comment: resize the result window and you'll see it.

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: seeing it in chrome and ie (ie9 that is)

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following one.

```
input.one{ 
      position:absolute;
      top:16.5%; 
      left:12%; 
      display:block; 
      background:rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
      max-width:30%;
      min-width:50px;
      max-height:100px;
      min-height:1.7%;
     }
```

I have tested this with IE8. Check to see whether it fulfill your requirement. Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i don't like your approach using an image and put html element on top of that. 
But let's try this one.

```
        <div style="width:800px">
            <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_RNrl2Gr0VwI/TJXG8dG6oeI/AAAAAAAADFY/pq6J6WQIW60/s1600/Arkham+Sanitarium+Admission+Form+Sample.jpg">
        </div>
```

and change this css :

```
input.one {
position: absolute;
top: 163px;
left: 100px;
display: block;
background: rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
}
```

Comment: + for your "don't like" thought but absolute position can't work here, I guess.

Comment: you want to adjust something dynamically on static thing. That's why i don't like it and using absolute works fine here :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w388h/1/)

The issue is solved by using a percentage based padding-bottom to achieve responsive height in the text input.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#block{ float:left; width:100%; max-width: 1000px; min-width: 600px; position: relative; }

#content{
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#block img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

input.one{  
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
     position: relative; 
    top:15%; 
    left:12%; 
    display:block; 
    background:rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
}
#top-spacer {
     display: block;
     content: "Hello";
     padding-bottom: 21%;
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     clear: both;
}



 <div id="content">
          <div id="block">
                <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_RNrl2Gr0VwI/TJXG8dG6oeI/AAAAAAAADFY/pq6J6WQIW60/s1600/Arkham+Sanitarium+Admission+Form+Sample.jpg">
                    <div id ='top-spacer'></div>
            <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="fn" class="one">

        </div>
    </div><!--/content-->
```

Comment: this pretty much works, but the "top" css property for the input.one{ is ignored.  say i want to shift it to a lower line, or add an input.two{ (for a second input field), how does that work?

Comment: `:top` isn't working because I applied absolute position to  your image and made the input relative, to make is easier to position the elements down the page.  Try `margin-top:` instead

Comment: @user3659102 check this (http://jsfiddle.net/w388h/3/) this way you can add a class to move down by a percent, so you don't have to individually work out each margin from the top of the page